# Win32 DrawText Colour and Display

Tags: c++, winapi, drawtext

I'm trying to display some text on my window. I'm using Win32/OpenGL with c++.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429541/displaying-string-output-in-a-window-using-c-in-win32-api) which is the method I'm trying to implement, unfortunately, I'm doing something wrong as it's not working.

This is my CALLBACK function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    LONG    lRet = 0; 
    PAINTSTRUCT    ps;

    switch (uMsg)
    { 
    case WM_SIZE:
        if(!g_bFullScreen)
        {
            SizeOpenGLScreen(LOWORD(lParam),HIWORD(lParam));
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &g_rRect);
        }
        break; 
    case WM_PAINT:
        //BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        //adding code from SO question here
         HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);  //line 403

            RECT rec;
            //       SetRect(rect, x ,y ,width, height)
            SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255,255,255))
            SetRect(&rec,10,10,100,100);
            //       DrawText(HDC, text, text length, drawing area, parameters "DT_XXX")
            DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Text Out String"),strlen("Text Out String"), &rec, DT_TOP|DT_LEFT);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

        //EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
       case WM_KEYDOWN: //line 418
                    //some key presses

   case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break; 

    default://line 510
        lRet = DefWindowProc (hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 
        break; 
    } 

    return lRet;
}
```

I seem to be implementing something wrong or overlooking something because I just can't see it.

It errors with this: `\main.cpp(403) : see declaration of 'hdc'`

If someone could suggest an edit or help me with where I'm going wrong, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

**update**

There's are the errors (added lines to code above):

```
main.cpp(418): error C2360: initialization of 'hdc' is skipped by 'case' label
main.cpp(506): error C2360: initialization of 'hdc' is skipped by 'case' label
main.cpp(510): error C2361: initialization of 'hdc' is skipped by 'default' label
```

Comment: Could you give us the full error message (this looks like only half of it) and mark which line is 403?

Comment: @Reanimation Put everything since just after `case WM_PAINT:` and until just before `case WM_KEYDOWN:` into `{ }`.

Comment: You don't need the ReleaseDC() after the EndPaint().  EndPaint() releases the DC automatically.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for highlighting that. I'll remove it :D Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't declare a variable in the middle of a `switch` statement. It must either be inside a block, or declared before the beginning of the `switch`.

Just put the code inside the `case` in brackets `{}` and the error will go away.

Comment: Oh yeh! What a silly mistake. The errors have gone, the program builds. Unfortunately, the text only appears to display for a split second before the graphics rendering is done, I'm guess there's an issue with OpenGL somewhere now. Thanks for posting.